# Using Vitis Debugger to view contents of DDR memory of Arty Z7 FPGA during program execution

Tags: c, fpga

I am using an Arty Z7 and storing certain data in DDR memory and would like to view the contents of memory during the execution of my program. I would like to do this so I can ensure what I am storing in memory is what I expect. Is this possible to do this in the Vitis debugger and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this is possible to do in Vitis! I'm using Vitis 2020.2 but the steps should be largely the same in any version.

1. Start a debug session
2. Pause execution
3. [Click "Window > Memory Browser"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p9Mt.png)
4. [A memory browser tab opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySVcs.png)

   1. You can drag this tab to a different area if you like
5. [Enter an address or expression in the box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnLxP.png)
6. You can scroll the memory view to quickly access nearby memory addresses instead of typing them in.